# Windows Forms Designer, Rationale behind Design > GenerateMember

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

In Visual Studio, while working on Windows Forms Applications a certain option can be found in the Form Design View. I'm talking about the `GenerateMember` option (under the `Design` section of the Properties Window).

The description of this option is the following:

> Indicates if a member variable will be generated for this component.

So, if I create a text box **`tb1`** using the Form Dessigner into my Form **`f1`** and I set this option to `false`, then I cannot access the control within the code (neither **`f1.tb1`** nor **`tb1`** exists).

There should be a good reason for doing that, but I don't know what this reason could be, that's why I'm asking:

- Whats the rationale behind the `Design` > `GenerateMember` option?
- What things can be achieved setting this option to false that cannot be achieved with it on true?
- In What situations I should preffer to *hide* the control setting `GenerateMember` to false instead of letting it to have the default value (true)?

Thank you.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rprabhu/archive/2004/05/06/127035.aspx any use? - whence " if you have any components that you are not really referencing **outside of InitializeComponent**, you can set it to false.", my emphasis

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When `GenerateMember` is set to `false`, instead of having a lot of private fields scoped to the Form class instance, they are created scoped to the `InitializeComponent()` method - meaning you will no longer have `this.btnOk` or `this.btnCancel` accessible to anything within your form.

I've figured it is, for the most part, just a personal preference. By specifying which controls you want directly visible as private fields to the rest of your form class, you can avoid getting lost in a sea of unused fields when modifying your code.

Other than that, there is no real functional difference. You could still access the controls via: `this.Controls` collection.